# How to use powershell to get the specific xml element?

Tags: c#, xml, powershell

Currently we have a xml file such as :

```
<file>
 <dircetory name="test">
  <directory name="test1">
   <directory name="test2"></directory>
  </directory>
 </directory>
 <directory name="test2">
 </directory>
</file>
```

The xml structure is not stable, but I need to get the xml node by name attribute

Now I get the "test2" string, and try to get the `<directory name="test2"></directory>` element, I could use foreach to iterator one by one, but is there any elegent way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "xml structure is not stable"?

Comment: I mean the <direcotry> maybe has a lot of <directory> sub element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an XPath expression like this to find the relevant nodes:

```xml
//*[@name='test2']
```

Then use the `Select-Xml` cmdlet and a `foreach` loop to iterate over the matching nodes:

```
foreach($result in Select-Xml -Path document.xml -XPath "//*[@name='test2']"){
    # Work with $result.Node in here
}
```